# Azure openAI Studio uploading training data status error

Tags: azure-openai, data-files

I can't upload the training data jsonl to Data files. Status becomes "error".

I have checked my jsonl file format - that should be correct, I'm using UTF-8 encoding.

I can upload the file successfully but then the status is error and I can't use the file. What could be wrong? Can this be something to do with my storage account? If so what should I check from the storage account config? Please help.